# difficult CSS positioning problem

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, onscroll

I have a CSS layout as in the attached picture.
[image]
I'd like to achieve the following behaviour

1. When part of the header is visible the positions (when scrolling) are as in the picture.
2. When header is invisible (we're scrolling down more then header length), the positions of left, right and img should be fixed and the only scrollable part should be page content.

So far [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R57b7/) link

Liam suggested [this](http://demo.marcofolio.net/create_a_sticky_sidebar_or_box/) link but javascript has error `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function .` Maybe it's related to the mootools (I'm not using it). Is this functionality possible without mootols?

Could you help me with positioning style of this?

thank you

Comment: No one can help you unless you post some meaningful code or at least a fiddler link to something that shows code doing what you say it's doing.

Comment: You need to also add your HTML so far.

Comment: @NGLN @Joel Etherton - code added

Comment: make a fiddle please with real data

Comment: @diEcho I don't have experience with fiddle yet. Could you please start something minimal for me and send link here and I will expand it with my code?

Comment: just paste the code on http://www.jsfiddle.net and click on save then it will generate a url, u only need to share that url here

Comment: I can't just paste, it's Drupal template, so there is a lot of irelevant code.

Comment: So are you just after plain HTML/CSS that looks and behaves like your image/description? Is the site fixed width (if so, how wide?) or fluid width?

Comment: Your use of the term `img` to describe the area below the sidebar is really confusing. If it's an `<img/>` how does it have expanding links? If it's not an `<img/>`... why use the term `img`?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen I'm sorry. This was my mistype. I will correct it.

Comment: Regarding question 1, would it be possible to have a `<div>` around `#right` and `#img` and set that parent `<div>` as `position: fixed`? This way, you could have `#right` and `#img` not positioned and `#img` would move down if `#right` expanded.

Comment: @Paul Sham Could you add it to my fiddle? I don't understand how you think it, because there is nothing about right sidebar in point 1.

Comment: Are the points 1 and 2 independent? If so, I could make from point 1 another question.

Comment: If I understand, you want the sidebars to scroll normally, **until** the header is off screen.  Then they should stop and stay fixed in place.  When the header returns to view, they should release and scroll normally as long as the header is in view.  You will absolutely need JavaScript to accomplish this.  The key will be to make a handler for the onScroll event which checks whether the header is on screen. If so, it should set the sidebars to position: static.  If not, it should set them to position: fixed.

Comment: @Will Martin Look [here](http://demo.marcofolio.net/create_a_sticky_sidebar_or_box/) and into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this, works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onscroll = function()
{
    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 221 || self.pageYOffset > 221) {
            $('rightsidebar').style.position = 'fixed';
            $('rightsidebar').style.top = '0';
            $('leftsidebar').style.position = 'fixed';
            $('leftsidebar').style.top = '0';
        } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 221 || self.pageYOffset < 221) {
            $('rightsidebar').style.position = 'absolute';
            $('rightsidebar').style.top = '221px';
            $('leftsidebar').style.position = 'absolute';
            $('leftsidebar').style.top = '221px';
        }
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body {margin:0;
}
#header {background:blue; height:221px;}
#rightsidebar {
        position:absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 221px;
        width: 150px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background:red;
}

#leftsidebar {
        position:absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 221px;
        width: 150px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
}
#topleft {background:green;}
#image {background:red;}
#footer {height:100px; background:yellow;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="leftsidebar">
<div id="topleft">lkjlk</div>
<div id="image">IMAGE</div>
</div>
<div id="content"><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /></div>
<div id="rightsidebar">lkjlk</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Must it be dependent on google API? What if google API does not work some day?

Comment: Is this [amount](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.js) of code needed?

Comment: No it's not dependant on the Google lib, you could download the mootools library and host it locally, I only used the hosted lib to show it working.

You could go through the library and remove redundant code, I just posted a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/juSvJ/
that should help.

Unless one's screen is really small, it should work no matter.

Comment: This doesn't do what I wrote in points 1 and 2. Maybe it wants some javascript as Liam suggested.

Comment: Yes point 1 just needs something like a javacript or you will have to make it so it moves around with will make the image RIGHT under the text. maybe putting some massive<br> will help it put it further away, but I don't think that is what you want. For point 2, I don't really understand what you are saying is it like http://jsfiddle.net/juSvJ/7/ but you want the sidebars to follow up and stay fixed like that?

Comment: Javascript is rather for point 2. I'd like to do point 1 with img position relative to left sidebar position (if it's possible).

Comment: putting a relative will work like `<br>`. It is possible, but when there is too much text and img keeps on going down, you will manually have to lower the `top:000px;`

Comment: @zzlawizz Is it possible for img to be always 5px below left sidebar? Left sidebar is changing its height because of collapse/expanse link

Comment: @zzlawizz When I expand the link in left sidebar, image which was 5px below suddenly jumps about 50px to the right and 50px to the top.

Comment: @zzlawizz I'm sorry, this was my fault. I have another HTML code for front page. Your solution for point 1 works.

Comment: @zzlawizz Please, paste your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143750/image-below-sidebar)