# Image below sidebar

Tags: css, positioning

I have a CSS layout as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x70p.png) picture.

I'd like to achieve the following behaviour

img should be always below left sidebar (as in the picture). Problem is that left sidebar contains a list of collapse/expand links and when you expand it the img overlaps with left sidebar and text is unreadable.

thank you

Comment: And what html are you using? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: You say please don't solve it - it was solved elsewhere, yet that wasn't an edit to the question - meaning you knew it was already solved `before` posting it. So why post then?

Comment: I splitted [original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138007/difficult-css-positioning-problem) question to two parts to lower confusion. Part one was solved. It seems that parts are independent.

Comment: @KP, there is a five-minute grace where edits aren't saved as an 'edit.'

Comment: You are going to have to post the code so we can see why the image is not moving with the left container.

Comment: -1 for splitting the question and adding confusion to the system. If you are not satisfied with the initial solution, why not post the additional requirement there and resolve it as you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">ert</div>
    <div id="left-sidebar">sdfsdfsdft
        <div id="img">IMG</div></div>
    <div id="right-sidebar">ert</div>
    <div id="content">aaert</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    background: url("img.png") red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top; 
    height: 125px;
    margin:-10px -10px 0px -10px;
}

#left-sidebar {
    left: 0; 
    height:2000px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
}

#right-sidebar {
    right:0;
    position: fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:2000px;
    background:green;
}
#img {
    border:1px solid;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:175px;
    height:175px;
}

#content {
    margin-left:-10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:130px;
    left:208px;
    right:208px;
    border:1px solid;
    Height:100%;
}
```